# React-native Display of AutoHeightWebView causes crash in Android 10 and Android 11

Tags: react-native

I seldom ask a question but want to see whether someone has a similar experience.

In coding a react-native app, I've included the component AutoHeightWebView on a page (together with other components, such as text and images.)

A strange behaviour occurs is that when the app is installed in physical devices:

> For devices of Android 9 and below: normal

> For devices of Android 10 and 11: app will crash when this page is displayed (say navigated from another page)

The following is extract of the code

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react';
import AutoHeightWebView from 'react-native-autoheight-webview'
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'

// other imports

export default class NdetailScreen extends Component {

        
render(){
        
return (

<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
     
     <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}>
     
<Image
  resizeMode={'contain'}
  style={{ width: '100%', height: 200 }}
  source={{uri: this.state.homepic}}
/>

        <AutoHeightWebView
    style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width , marginTop: 0 }}
      source={{ uri: 'https://xxxxxx.com/nshow.php?serial=' + this.props.route.params.unitserial + '&lang=' + this.props.route.params.lang  }}
    scalesPageToFit={false}
    viewportContent={'width=device-width, user-scalable=no'}

  />

<View style={{height:80}}><Text> ... other text </Text></View>

</ScrollView>

</View>           
      
)
}
}
```

The strange thing is, if I remove the following block, everything works fine (in the Android 10 and 11 smartphones):

```
<AutoHeightWebView
    style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width , marginTop: 0 }}
      source={{ uri: 'https://xxxxxx.com/nshow.php?serial=' + this.props.route.params.unitserial + '&lang=' + this.props.route.params.lang  }}
    scalesPageToFit={false}
    viewportContent={'width=device-width, user-scalable=no'}

  />
```

Any advice ?

Comment: as a side note, why you didn't use the RN community WebView? is there any limitation with it? https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Reason:  I want the webview to have auto adjustment of height according to the contents of the page, hence I use AutoHeightWebView instead of WebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a bug of AutoHeightWebView (because I have already used the most up-dated version of AutoHeightWebView and my expo / npm versions are all up-to-date.

After repeatedly observing the "crash" behaviour, I have found that if I've removed the AutoHeightWebView part, there will NOT be any crash. So it can be run without problem in an Android 10/11 devices. After that if I re-added the AutoHeightWebView part -- there will be no crash ! (you know it can be done by real-time updating of code when the device is connected to the expo development platform)

So if the AutoHeightWebView part is already there while I navigate to the screen, it will crash in the Android 10/11 devices, but if it is "added" LATER, it will be fine.

Hence, I have used a trick to fix the problem.

1. change the code so that the AutoHeightWebView part will NOT be rendered when the page is first loaded
2. in the componentDidMount() part, add a setTimeout function (say 0.5 second) to change a control state so that the AutoHeightWebView will be rendered again after 0.5 seconds when the page is loaded

The following is the code

```
constructor() {
super();
this.state={xxtime4:0}
}

componentDidMount() {

setTimeout(() => {
this.setState({xxtime4:'10'});   
  }, 500);
   }


kenlist3() {
if (this.state.xxtime4==0) { 
return null
} else {
     return (
    <AutoHeightWebView
    style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width , marginTop: 0 }}
   
   source={{ uri: 'https://www.xxxxx.com/displaytext.php'  }}
    scalesPageToFit={false}
    viewportContent={'width=device-width, user-scalable=no'}
  />

)

} }
```

In this way, if I use {this.kenlist3()}, it will be able to display the AutoView in all the physical devices. (including Android 10/11).

I just hope that in future this bug will be fixed by the developer so that I do not need to use such a "trick". But at least it is fine for the time being.

Hope that the above can also help someone.

Comment: This doesn't work. I just tested it with a 10 seconds gap after first render.